Json parsing- array value - Azure stream Analytics
I am trying to explode the array value. But I am getting error `'Apply' can only be used with functions 'getarrayelements, getrecordproperties'.
select a.[id],row1.arrayvalue from input a

CROSS APPLY

[row] AS row1

Input data is
[

  {

    "id": "ada1",

    "row": [1,2,3]

  },

  {

    "id": "ada2",

    "row": [5,4,7,9]

  }

]

output expected:

id,row

ada1,1

ada1,2

ada1,3

ada2,5

ada2,4

ada2,7

ada2,9


select a.[id],row1.arrayvalue from input a

CROSS APPLY

[row] AS row1


Use the below code to achieve your requirement.
select rakeshinput.id,row.ArrayValue as row1 from rakeshinput CROSS  APPLY  GetArrayElements(rakeshinput.row)  as  row;

Output:

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-parsing-json#convert-array-elements-into-separate-events
